# Gradle build fails in CI when run in parallel for 2 branches with shared .gradle folder

Tags: gradle

Given I have Gradle project with Gradle wrapper enabled.

Content of gradle-wrapper.properties is following:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

When I execute `./gradlew clean build` task for 2 branches in CI in parallel, first build continues to run to completion and second build fails because of:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Cannot create service of type SettingsLoaderFactory using BuildScopeServices.createSettingsLoaderFactory() as there is a problem with parameter #4 of type ClassLoaderScopeRegistry.
    > Cannot create service of type ClassLoaderScopeRegistry using BuildScopeServices.createClassLoaderScopeRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #2 of type ClassLoaderCache.

 Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/home/buildagent/.gradle/caches/5.6.4' when creating directory '/home/buildagent/.gradle/caches/5.6.4/generated-gradle-jars'
```

Why do these builds clash?

How can I keep caching of downloaded dependencies and avoid build clashes?

Comment: can you post the entire command being used to run `clean build`?  It should be something like `./gradlew clean build` to invoke the wrapper.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I execute. I updated the question

Comment: does `./gradlew --version` give you the expected version?  also try running `./gradlew clean build --stacktrace`

Comment: I tried it and I witnessed behavior when sometimes it works and sometimes if fails on exceptions I posted in the question.. I will post details once it fails again

Comment: I'm getting these exceptions when I run 2 builds in parallel in Teamcity.. I know that `.gradle` folder is shared for both runs.. is it possible that these 2 builds clash in some way when operating on the same `.gradle` folder? `.gradle` is actually `GRADLE_USER_HOME`
I also added exception from stacktrace to the question

Comment: I also now update question to be more precise